# Align="center" not working

Tags: css, html

Is there better ways to center an object by HTML other than align=""? Align doesn't always work. Are there other tags that can help with this?

```
 <html>
 <font align="center" size="45"> Hello World </p>
 </html>
```

This code would not align the font tag in the center. I know there are ways with CSS but are there any other ways in HTML

Comment: Both the `<font>` element and align attribute were deprecated ages ago and removed from HTML5. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features

Comment: HTML is not for styling, that's what CSS is for. Apart from that as others have said; both the `<font>` tag and the `align` attribute are deprecated

Comment: A tip for all future problems, right-click on your page in browser and click "inspect element".

Comment: Ahhhh I only use them if I'm doing a small project and I know about inspect element....

Comment: <font> and <center> are more than deprecated. They are now marked as obsolete: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features You should not be surprised, one day, if they don't work at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `style` attribute inside your paragraph:

`<p style="text-align: center;">Hello world!</p>`

the `<font>` tag has been deprecated for quite some time.  Other answers are also suggesting the `<center>` tag, however, this is also deprecated.  (so is the `<align>` tag.)

*NOTE: You forgot to open your `<p>` tag.*

Answer (score 2):

The `<font>` tag was used for styling, not marking up a section of your content. Hence it's deprecated, along with tags such as `<center>`.

For best practise, keep your styles in CSS and your markup in HTML

Use:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Your text</p>
```

Also it is advisable to use a separate CSS file or block, keep inline CSS rules to a minimum (as these will take precedence over a CSS rule in a CSS file)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using

`text-align="center"`

Also, you have a closing "p" tag, but no opening "p" tag?

EDIT: Wrote it out for you

```
 <html>
 <p style=text-align="center" size="45"> Hello World </p>
 </html>
```

However, you should style your CSS in a seperate style sheet, since HTML is not ideal, and neither is inline-styling.

css:

```
p{
text-align:center;
font-size:45pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
<div style="font-size:45px; text-align:'center'">Hello World </div>
</html>
```

Because the `<font>` as well as the attributes that you have used in it are now obsolete.
All styling is done through the style property of the tag.

Comment: You should try explaining WHY they should do it this way.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `<center></center>` I suppose.

Comment: `<center>`, like `<font>` was deprecated ages ago and removed entirely from HTML5. http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/center